# Apache ActiveMQ AMQP Spring Boot AWS

Tags: activemq-classic, amqp, spring-amqp

I have an ActiveMQ AWS service with protocol AMQP. AWS returns to me:

```
failover:(amqp+ssl://b-ca138bd4-e6c4-4596-8329-f11bebf40111-1.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:5671,amqp+ssl://b-ca138bd4-e6c4-4596-8329-f11bebf40111-2.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:5671)
```

I am trying to implement using Spring Boot the connection with that endpoint, but I have many problems. I have tried with many ways, but I can't connect to the ActiveMQ using Spring.

I have tried:

Creating many configuration Beans, like:

```
@Bean
fun connectionFactory(): ConnectionFactory {
    val activeMQConnectionFactory = ActiveMQConnectionFactory()
    activeMQConnectionFactory.brokerURL = "amqp+ssl://b-ca138bd4-e6c4-4596-8329-f11bebf40111-1.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:5671"
    activeMQConnectionFactory.trustedPackages = listOf("com.rappi.scaffolding")
    return activeMQConnectionFactory
}
```

and using many dependencies like:

```
implementation("org.apache.activemq:activemq-spring:5.17.0")
implementation("org.springframework:spring-jms")
```

and

```
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-artemis")
```

But is not possible for me establish the connection. At this moment I am seeing this error:

```
Reason: java.io.IOException: Transport scheme NOT recognized: [amqp+ssl]
```

There are some example in Java or Kotlin or guide to connect me with AWS using AMQP protocol? I didn't find any in Google.

I have read that using QPid, but it not works for me.

I have found many examples using Rabbit, but not Apache ActiveMQ protocol amqp+ssl.

Finally It works using the Bean:

```
@Bean
    fun connectionFactory(): ConnectionFactory {
        return JmsConnectionFactory(
            "failover:(amqps://b-ca138bd4-e6c4-4596-8329-f11bebf40111-1.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:5671,amqps://b-ca138bd4-e6c4-4596-8329-f11bebf40111-2.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:5671)").apply {
            this.username = user
            this.password = passwordAQ
        }
```

Comment: In what way exactly is AWS returning `failover:(amqp+ssl://b-ca138bd4-e6c4-4596-8329-f11bebf40111-1.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:5671,amqp+ssl://b-ca138bd4-e6c4-4596-8329-f11bebf40111-2.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:5671)` to you? That does not look like a URL which the Qpid JMS client would use.

Comment: at this moment:

 Reason: java.io.IOException: Transport scheme NOT recognized: [amqp+ssl]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things wrong with your code and configuration.

**First**, the URL you're using for your client is incorrect. The `amqp+ssl` scheme is not valid for any client. That's the scheme used to define the connector in the ActiveMQ broker configuration.

**Second**, your dependencies are wrong. As far as the client goes you just need:

```
implementation("org.apache.qpid:qpid-jms-client:1.6.0")
```

Of course, if you're using Spring you'll need all the related Spring dependencies, but as far as the client itself goes this is all you need.

**Third**, your code is wrong. You should be using something like this:

```
@Bean
fun connectionFactory(): ConnectionFactory {
    return new org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsConnectionFactory("failover:(amqps://b-ca138bd4-e6c4-4596-8329-f11bebf40111-1.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:5671,amqps://b-ca138bd4-e6c4-4596-8329-f11bebf40111-2.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:5671)");
}
```

Comment: Show me it:
Type mismatch.
Required:
ConnectionFactory
Found:
JmsConnectionFactory

Comment: You may need to use version `1.6.0` of `qpid-jms-client`. I updated my answer to clarify this. Version 1.6.0 of `org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsConnectionFactory` implements `javax.jms.ConnectionFactory` whereas 2.0.0 implements `jakarta.jms.ConnectionFactory`.

Comment: Thanks, and this error sounds to you:

Client failed to authenticate using SASL: ANONYMOUS

Comment: It works for me, I have updated the Bean with the configuration that works!!! thanks a lot

Comment: And using amqps instead of amqp+ssl